# How to detect app was reopened after changing settings?

Tags: permissions, flutter, settings

I am using [simple permissions plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions#-readme-tab-) to request contacts permissions in my flutter app.

When user presses on 'Don't ask Again' option and denies the permission, I am giving a button which opens settings using openSettings().
Now, if User enables the permissions and presses back to come on the app, how do I detect that permission has been granted?

Here is some code to give an idea-

```
Text(
  'Permission to access Contacts was denied.\nPlease press Settings to provide permissions and continue connecting!',
),
MaterialButton(
  onPressed: () {
    SimplePermissions.openSettings();
  },
  child: Text('Settings'),
)
```

Comment: Hello, did my answer fix your issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [WidgetsBindingObserver class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html). It allows you to detect the lifecycle of a widget.
Extend your current state `with WidgetsBindingObserver` and add these lines to your initState.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this); //this sets WidgetsBindingObserver
requestPermission(); //this will request the permission on initial load.
```

Add the following lines to your state.

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  checkPermission(); //this will check the status of permission when the user returns back from the settings page.
}


checkPermission() async {
  bool res = await SimplePermissions.checkPermission(Permission.Camera);
  if (!res) {
    setState(() {
      _statusMessage = "waiting for camera permission";
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      _statusMessage = "camera permission has been granted";
    });
  }
}
```

Check the full example code [here](https://gist.github.com/westdabestdb/d6c7b9a008016b44bd6fa19b645d33e7).

Comment: Hey, Could you please explain the code? When do I open the settings? I have never used WidgetsBindingObserver class.

Comment: @KeertiPurswani How would you like me to explain it ?

Comment: Sorry, I had missed your comment. Could you check this out and help if possible - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55299988/why-is-my-applifecyclestate-resumed-twice