# Why is my "AppLifecycleState" "resumed" twice?

Tags: dart, flutter, state, lifecycle

I am using [call_number](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/call_number) plugin to make a call from my app. I am tracking the `AppLifecycleState` to take actions. This is the order in which states are changing-

```
AppLifecycleState.inactive
AppLifecycleState.resumed
AppLifecycleState.inactive
AppLifecycleState.paused
AppLifecycleState.inactive
AppLifecycleState.resumed
```

Last 4-I understand the flow, but I am unable to understand why is state changing to `resumed` the first time. According to the documentation - "The application is visible and responding to user input." when it is in resumed state but when I press button, call is directly placed. 
I wonder if it is being done by the plugin in background but I don't see my app coming up even for a split second.